# 'npm install' not working Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, path, npm, gruntjs

I am trying to download the grunt package with npm. Whenever I try to install something with npm, it takes forever, and literally doesn't get done. I thought maybe it had something to do with the version. When I try to update npm, it does the same thing. The install command just doesn't work.

I am checking that status code of the request, and it is always 200. However, the spinner keeps spinning.

I am using versions:

node v6.2.0

npm v3.8.9

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is torture.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your `package.json` looks like?

Comment: Have you tried updating your node? Try using the .msi installed provided by nodejs.com

Comment: @orlandomarinella yes, but it does the same thing. I also uninstalled node.js and reinstalled it with windows installer, so everything is up to date. Still does not work